# How to pass-through directives from custom component to it's children?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I know how to use `@Input()` decorator but what I am asking is how to pass directives that weren't explicitly programmed to be Input, especially validators on custom input component

My goal is to build input component that accepts few pre-set directives to provide Label, field name etc. and have ability to pass all remaining directives to underlying input element.

Even better would be passing validators array as a directive of custom-input and using it to insert directives to underlying input + building validation messages from it, but at worst case I can mix these two approaches

Is it even possible?

Edit: I'm not really sure what kind of pseudocode should I provide but I'll do my best

```
<div>
  <ion-label>{{labelText}}</ion-label>
  <ion-input [type]="(inputType) ? inputType : 'text'" [name]="fieldName"></ion-input>
  <div *ngIf="field.errors && (field.dirty||field.touched)" class="error-contener">    
    <div class="error-message" *ngIf="field.errors?.required">Field is required</div>
  </div>
</div>



@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  templateUrl: 'custom-input.html',
})

export class CustomInputComponent{

  @Input() fieldName: string;
  @Input() labelText: string;
  @Input() inputType: string;
  @Input() validatorsArray: any[];

  constructor(){}

}
```

that's basically completely dumbed down version of the component with imports omitted, and now the best solution would be the ability to add directives to the `<ion-input>` tag based off `validatorsArray` and some custom code translating it (other parts of array used to build the errors below), but I would be fine if I was able to just pass every directive from `<custom-input>` tag that isn't explicitly listed as Input down to the `<ion-input>` tag

Comment: Can you provide at least some kind of pseudo code or file structure? There is a few ways of doing this so I would need a more concrete example

Comment: @undefinedMayNotBeNull I edited my question, I hope now it's more understandable what I am trying to achieve (the thing is building a form with all this markup is a terrible lots of boilerplate and in the upcoming future we may even be making these forms based off data from server)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to implement NgValueAccessor [Have a look at this guide](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/).

This way you can use [Angulars Form API](https://angular.io/guide/forms) with your custom component. 
You can then use Angular and HTML form validation.

Ideally you will have:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <custom-input formControlName="user" type="text" required></custom-input>
  <custom-input formControlName="password" type="password" required></custom-input>
</form>
```

TS:

```
public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    user: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, yourValidator])
})
```

If you implement custom Validators also make sure to use Angulars API. [Here is a guide for custom validation.](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: the directives passed down would include my own validators if it makes any difference, I'll give it a good read and hope it will work as I expect it to, thank you

Comment: I added some more info to the answer. it is all possible and should be done using the API